# Convergence in q-norm expectation question

Tags: convergence-divergence

Use the triangle inequality for the norm on $L^{q}$ to show that if $q \geq 1$ and $X_{n} \rightarrow^{q.m} X$ (converges in q mean) then
$$E[|X_{n}|^{q}] \rightarrow E[|X|^{q}]$$

So far, I've tried figuring out how to extend the triangle inequality to powers of $q$. I've tried relating $$|X_{n} - X|^{q}$$
to different values, but I'm not sure if the inequality
$$|X_{n} - X|^{q} \leq |X_{n}|^{q} - |X|^{q}$$ holds in all scenarios. I was trying this because I'm assuming that once I can get a relation between different expressions, it is simple to extend this to expectation.
I've also tried experimenting first with the simple triangle inequality by noting that
$|(X_{n} - X) + X| \leq |X_{n} - X| + |X|$ but again can't extend this to powers of q. I'm not entirely sure where to start exactly.

Comment: I suppose you should use this version of the triangle inequality:
$|\Vert X_n\Vert_q - \Vert X\Vert_q| \leq \Vert X_n - X\Vert_q$.
What you know about the RHS tells you something about the LHS.

Comment: From this, I can see that the RHS approaches 0 as n approaches infinity. This would ultimately tell us that 
$$\lim _{n \to \infty}(E[|X_{n}|^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (E[|X|^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}}$$
which in turn tell us that 
$$\lim _{n \to \infty}(E[|X_{n}|^{q}) \leq (E[|X|^{q})$$
I'm not entirely sure how to make the final conclusion of equality. I'm sure it's just a small detail, but I can't pinpoint what exactly it is...

Comment: You can make use of the absolute on the LHS (then use continuity of $y^q$).

Comment: Thanks so much!